# Which verb collocates with the word 'heresy'?

Tags: verbs, collocation

When talking about the first people who were known to believe or do something considered heretical, which verb do we use with the word *heresy*? I want the verb for the 'invention' of the heresy - not a person who just follows it.

For example: 'They (past verb) this heresy in the second century.'

Comment: Prosaically enough, 'introduce heresy' is used (if not exactly common).

Comment: There is no special word for the introduction of a heretical idea, even in the narrow sense of condemned Christian doctrine. Any word for the development and spread of an idea is suitable. It is *introduced*, *developed* and *advanced*; it is *conceived*, *proposed*, and *promoted*; it is *incubated*, *cultivated*, and *forwarded*; etc.

Comment: [Google collocate search to the rescue](http://googlebooks.byu.edu/?c=us&q=49635379) - or not. As @choster already wrote, there is no special word. **Conceived** does however appear in the collocate list ;)

Answer (score 5):

**"espouse"** might be the verb you're looking for. -  **A person espouses a heresy.**

> [**"espouse"**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/espouse) - to make one's own; adopt or embrace, as a cause.
>
> - "Those who **espouse** the “heresy of Luther,” are legitimate only if they are graced by God"
> - ".....they **espouse the heresy** that it is the president who knows best"
> - "The founder or leader of a heretical movement is called a heresiarch, while individuals who **espouse heresy or commit heresy**, are known as heretics." [**Societies, Network and Transitions**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=N5EkAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT351&dq=espouse+a+heresy&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWypCxzMnOAhXIGJAKHZbFCGAQ6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=espouse%20a%20heresy&f=false)

**EDIT**

You could say that "According to the Holy See, Martin Luther **conceived, established and disseminated** that heresy (the protestant reformation) in the sixteenth century.

Comment: Thanks, but I want the verb for the 'invention' of the heresy - not a person who just follows it. So, in your example it's Luther who 'invented' the heresy.

Answer (score 3):

They **promulgated** this heresy in the second century.

From Merriam-Webster:

> Synonym Discussion of Promulgate
>
> Declare, announce, proclaim, promulgate mean to make known publicly.
>   Declare implies explicitness and usually formality in making known
>   . Announce implies the
>   declaration of something for the first time . Proclaim implies declaring clearly,
>   forcefully, and authoritatively . **Promulgate implies the proclaiming of a dogma,
>   doctrine, or law** .